# How I can figure out if my cluster is damaged

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

I have some problems with my hard disk and I was wondering if one the causes of the malfunction could be a broken cluster. 
Do you have any idea if I can discover if that's the problem?

Comment: Run a utility that checks the disk.

Comment: Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.